# Add <style> and <script> from body and place it on head

Tags: jquery, spring-mvc, spring-roo, jspx

I am using Spring Roo 1.2.4 for this topic. I am aware that to add user-defined default styles and scripts should be added on `PROJECT_FOLDER/src/main/webapp/WEB-INF/tags/util/load-scripts.tagx`. In my case, I have some `.jspx` that need(s) additional style and scripts on a particular view only.

<strike>When I view the page with the `<style>` and `<script>` tags on the `.jspx` file, the `<style>` gets rendered and work accordingly. But the `<script>` tag doesn't work especially when using the JQuery library for dialog. *I have added the jquery libraries on the scripts folder under webapp.*</strike>

> Already fixed because `jquery.js` was rendered below `jquery-ui.js` in which `jquery.js` should be rendered first.

Having a `<style>` and `<script>` tag in the body section might not be advisable due to HTML standards. Is there a way to have the `<style>` and `<script>` tags on a particular `.jspx` be render on the `<head>` section instead of having them rendered on the `<body>` section?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Java,

I think what i would do is the following 3 steps.  I based my solution on how some pages can have the menu defined and some dont'.  Same basic principle.

## Add a template placholder into the default layout

That is, inside of /src/main/webapp/WEB-INF/layouts/default.jspx,  add the a tiles:insertAttribute tag with ignore=true, such as following to the head:

```
    <!-- FIXME Can't move scripts to the bottom of 
      page because of how spring tags do the fields-->
    <util:load-scripts />
    <tiles:insertAttribute name="pagespecificscripts" ignore="true" />

    <spring:message code="application_name" var="app_name" htmlEscape="false"/>
    <title><spring:message code="welcome_h3" arguments="${app_name}" /></title>
</head>
```

## Add the page specific scripts to the same folder as the view

That is, if your entity is named "pizza", add the following to /src/main/webapp/WEB-INF/views/people :

```
<jsp:root xmlns:c="http://java.sun.com/jsp/jstl/core" xmlns:fn="http://java.sun.com/jsp/jstl/functions" xmlns:jsp="http://java.sun.com/JSP/Page" xmlns:spring="http://www.springframework.org/tags" version="2.0">
    <script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.9.1.min.js" type="text/javascript"><!-- required for FF3 and Opera --></script>
    <script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jqueryui/1.10.3/jquery-ui.min.js" type="text/javascript"><!-- required for FF3 and Opera --></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="http://www.alpacajs.org/js/alpaca.min.js"><!-- required for FF3 and Opera --></script>
    <script src="${areYouSure_js}" type="text/javascript"><!-- required for FF3 and Opera --></script>
    <link type="text/css" href="http://www.alpacajs.org/css/alpaca.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
</jsp:root>
```

## Define the tile definition attribute in the views.xml

Update the entity specific tiles views.xml to set the optional attribute we defined in step 1.  That is, add the following to /src/main/webapp/WEB-INF/views/people/views.xml:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" standalone="no"?>
<!DOCTYPE tiles-definitions PUBLIC "-//Apache Software Foundation//DTD Tiles Configuration 2.1//EN" "http://tiles.apache.org/dtds/tiles-config_2_1.dtd">
<tiles-definitions>
    <definition extends="default" name="people/list">
        <put-attribute name="body" value="/WEB-INF/views/pizza/list.jspx"/>
        <put-attribute name="pagespecificscripts" value="/WEB-INF/views/pizza/pagespecificscripts.jspx"/>
    </definition>
```

Those steps should get you on your way.

Hope that helps...

Comment: Do I need to create `pagespecificscripts.jspx` for each page that would need additional `<scripts>` and/or `<style>` or that specific page that would need it?

Comment: You could reuse it if you want to, or not, depending upon your situation.  The example that i have posted makes sense if you want it to apply to that specific page.  If you want to use it more globally, perhaps you want to up it in the src/main/webapp/WEB-INF/views directory, next to menu.jspx.  Maybe you could call it custom-load-scripts.jspx in that case.

Comment: Can you provide a sample project for me to follow through the instructions? I can't get your example to work and having difficulty setting-up multiple `<script>` and `<style>` tags to be placed on the `<head>` section. Sorry for the late response, I can't make this work.

Comment: I'm such a timid person. It now works perfectly thanks for the tip. But there a bit of a problem regarding file management, using this scenario each page would need more than one `.jspx` file (the page, its css file(s) and js file(s)). Is there a way to link in the `web.xml` the tag(s): `<script>` and `<link>` directly for file management on the project folder.

Comment: I'm not sure what you are asking.  I don't think the web.xml would likely be involved.  Are you want a variable substitution in the views.xml, reading definitions from web.xml?  You probably need to ask as a separate question because the answer comments are limiting.

Comment: I have already ask a different question base from your answer. Here's the [link](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18506830/springroo-placing-script-and-link-on-load-scripts-tagx-from-view-xml) for it.