# SpringRoo placing <script> and <link> on load-scripts.tagx from view.xml

Tags: spring-mvc, spring-roo, jspx, tagx

A best practice of web development is to place the `<styles>` and `<scripts>` on a particular page in `.css` and `.js` file respectively.

This question might be a duplicate from this [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18095139/add-style-and-script-from-body-and-place-it-on-head) and the answer from @java1337 get it working. From his answer file management can be an issue since for every definition of a view `(.jspx)` it is required to add another `.jspx` file containing all `<link href>` and `<scripts src>`.

One possible solution I'm working on is adding in the `view.xml` the URL/link of all `.css` and `.js` files that needed to be placed in the `<head>` section. Below is a sample of a `view.xml` is the structure I'm working on but I can get it working on the `load-scripts.tagx`

```
<definition extends="default" name="user/index">
   <put-attribute name="body" value="/WEB-INF/views/user/index.jspx" />
   <put-list-attribute name="scriptsList">
      <add-attribute value="/resources/scripts/user/script.js"/>
   </put-list-attribute>
</definition>
```

And on the `load-scripts.tagx`

```
<tiles:useAttribute id="list" name="scriptsList" classname="java.util.List"/> -->
<c:forEach var="script" items="${list }">
   <script text="text/javascript" src="${script }"></script>
</c:forEach>
```

From the structure above, I am getting an ServletException on the `default.jspx` file which might be caused by the `<tiles:useAttribute>`

**UPDATE:**

1. The answer of @java1337 not worked but file management can be an issue as stated above.
2. Updated the question for clarifications.

Comment: I don't see the question.  Are you getting an error when you edit the load-scripts.tagx?

Comment: From the answer from @java1337, I am not getting an error. But I'm trying to place `<script src>` and `<link href>` on `load-scripts.tagx` instead of placing them on another `.jspx` file.

Comment: I do this all the time.  You just edit the file and put the tags there.  Anything that uses the load-scripts tag would then get the edited file.

Comment: @CodeChimp you're saying that you're following the answer of @Jjava1337? Is there a way to get the structure above working?